# Samba doesn't apply allow/deny on config reload

Tags: samba

On a Ubuntu server with a SAMBA share, I am trying to allow access from some IP addresses and deny from others.

I configured `smb.conf` as follows:

```
[global]
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        server role = standalone server
        map to guest = Bad User
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        unix password sync = Yes
        syslog = 0
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
        dns proxy = No
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        idmap config * : backend = tdb

        hosts allow = 10.4. 10.162. localhost
        hosts deny = 10.4.114.125


[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        create mask = 0700
        printable = Yes
        browseable = No


[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers


[data]
        comment = Data Folder
        path = /data
        force user = devuser
        force group = devgroup
        group = devgroup
        read only = No
        create mask = 0660
        force create mode = 0664
        directory mask = 0774
        directory mode = 0774
        force directory mode = 0774
        guest ok = Yes
```

Then I reload the config by running `sudo smbcontrol all reload-config`.
Unfortunately I cannot restart the samba service because others are using it heavily.

After reloading the config, I can still access the share from my computer (10.4.114.125) although explicitely denied.
I tried rebooting my computer and it didn't change. Any ideas?

**EDIT**:  If I set the deny list not in the global section but the share specifically it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to kick everyone off of your samba server if you want modifications to take place. After everyone is offline, you can do a restart on the server and all modifications should take place.

Comment: Then why is there a "reload-config" option? This reload acutally seems to work for example if I create a new share in the config

Comment: If a computer with ip X currently modifying a file in a samba share Y , and you are trying to deny access for X to modify any share Y in samba, then first you will need to force X to eject share Y, and then you could hypothetically force Samba to reload its config file.